# JavaScript constructors

Tags: javascript, constructor

I do not understand quite completely how to apply constructors on this object creation method:

```
var MyObject = {
   ...
};
```

I know that you can do:

```
var MyObject = new Object();
MyObject.prototype.constructor = function(props)
{
  ...
}
```

or...

```
function MyObject(prop1, prop2)
{
 this.prop1 = prop1;
 ...
}
```

Can I do something like this?

```
var MyObject = {
   MyObject: function(prop1, prop2)
   {
     ...
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't, that would simply create a (static) method on MyObject -- `MyObject.MyObject`.  In JavaScript, a constructor *is* the class.  Class methods and properties are created either inside the constructor using `this.` or by adding to the prototype (outside of the constructor) using `MyClass.prototype.`.  You can think of "objects" in JavaScript as static classes.

Comment: I'm getting "MyObject.prototype is undefined" when I attempt to define the constructor by using MyObject.prototype.constructor = function() ... what could be wrong?

Comment: I wondered about this when you made your first post.  Functions/Classes are a mysterious world but I will try to explain what I think is happening.  An "Object" (`var o = new Object();`) is not a Function, therefore has no `prototype`.  You may be able to achieve what you want by defining it as a `new Function()` instead, however, I would just use `function o () { ... }` then add "members" to the class after that definition, using the prototype.

Comment: Yeah, I figured out it would be simpler that way. Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 1):

Example from [here](http://www.c-point.com/javascript_tutorial/constructor.htm)

**Creating constructors**

To write your own constructors, you use the this keyword within the constructor to refer to the newly-created object. The constructor initializes the object.

In the example below:

The make7Table constructor creates a multiplication table for number 7
The size property is introduced to keep track of the number of elements
The value of each element is initialized

```
function make7Table(numElements)
{
    this.size = numElements;
    var cnt;
    for(cnt = 0; cnt < numElements; cnt++)
    {
        this[cnt] = cnt*7;
    }
}

// Use the constructor to create and initialize an array.
myArray = new make7Table(10);
document.write(myArray[5]);
document.write("This table has " + myArray.size + " elements");
```

To run the code, paste it into JavaScript Editor, and click the Execute button. myArray[5] retrieves the element with the value of 5*7 = 35.

Answer (score 1):

```
var MyObject = new Object();
MyObject.prototype.constructor = function(props)
{
    ...
}
```

is the same as

```
var MyObject = {};
MyObject.prototype.constructor = function(props)
{
    ...
}
```