# Creating an object with a constructor and named members

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

How would you implement a constructor together with named functions on an object in JavaScript?

This is how I'd like to use the object:

```
o("..."); // use the object's constructor

o.namedFunction("..."); // use a named member on the object
```

**I don't want to have to "new up" object** before it's usable... You could say I want the equivalent of a static class with a bunch of static methods and a constructor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This did the trick:

```
var o = function ()
{
    return "constructor";
};

o.namedFn = function ()
{
    return "namedFn";
};

console.log(o("test"));
console.log(o.namedFn("test"));
console.log(o("test"));
```

Answer (score 0):

This [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096141/javascript-constructors) has several good suggestions and examples.  Also, be certain to use **new** when you create an instance/object.

```
var obj = new MyClass();
obj.someMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you want to have *static members* (*in class-based OO languages*) on your [constructor functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Guide/Creating_New_Objects/Using_a_Constructor_Function).

In JavaScript functions are [*first-class*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function) objects, that means they can have properties and they can be handled just as any object:

```
functon Ctor (arg) {
  //...
}
Ctor.namedFunction = function () {
  // "static" member
};


var instance = new Ctor("..."); // use the object's constructor
Ctor.namedFunction("..."); // use a named member on the object
```

Notice that I added the `namedFunction` property directly to the `Ctor` function object.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, just to be able to share some properties inside my methods by using closures:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>so</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        function fn(arg){
            var init = arg;
            return {
                meth:function(arg){
                    alert(init + arg);
                }
            };
        };
        var obj = fn('Stack');
        obj.meth('Overflow');
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Something you don't have by declaring them externally.